# AngularJS material FAB items are behind my toolbar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design

FABSpeedial items are being put behind a secondary toolbar that my page has. I would have expected these items to be displayed 'on top' of this toolbar.

Please reference this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxBGbp?editors=1000).  You will see the speeddial items (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) are being put behind the secondary toolbar (marked as 'Secondary header')

The `fab-actions` below are all appearing behind the `toolbar` instead of on top of it.  I would guess that this is some sort of `z-index` issue but I am not seeing where the index is coming from so that I can change it.

```
<md-fab-actions>
      <md-button aria-label="Twitter" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
       1
      </md-button>
      <md-button aria-label="Facebook" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
      2
      </md-button>
      <md-button aria-label="Google Hangout" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
       3
      </md-button>
</md-fab-actions>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set style like this `style="position:relative; z-index:1"` for Secondary header  `<md-toolbar style="position:relative; z-index:1">`

no need z-index to do that.Please reference this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvOmaW)

Comment: Such a simple solution.  I was way overthinking it, lol.  Thanks man.